# Why puppeteer gives me a wrong screenshot in width?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating a script to take screenshots of Web pages with the puppeteer, I don't understand why on this site the image is saved with a width greater than that which I have set, 1920px.

If I have the fixed width of the browser, why does the screenshot come out with a greater width?

I would like to save the screenshot with a fixed width of 1920px and height based on the total content of the page.
The width of the saved image should be as wide as the width of the browser, why doesn't this happen?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const os = require('os');
const username = require('username');

//I identify the operating system and the architect of the CPU to run the Google Chrome Patch
var architetturaCPU = os.arch();
var sistemaOperativo = os.type();
console.log('System OS: '+sistemaOperativo+' '+architetturaCPU);
//console.log(os.platform());

// Device width and height
const device_width = 1920;
const device_height = 1080;

//Patch di Chrome
var systemPath = '';
if (sistemaOperativo == 'Darwin'){
    console.log('Chrome for MacOS');
    var systemPath = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome';
} else
if(sistemaOperativo == 'Windows_NT' && architetturaCPU == 'x64'){
    console.log('Chrome for Windows 64bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}else
if(sistemaOperativo == 'Windows_NT' && architetturaCPU == 'x32'){
    console.log('Chrome for Windows 32bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}else
if(sistemaOperativo == 'Windows_NT' && architetturaCPU == 'ia32'){
    console.log('Chrome for Windows 32bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}



//I build an Array and insert all the buttons for the consent of the Cookies for the Network sites
const btncookie1 = 'button.cs-close-btn';
const btncookie2 = 'button.cs-accept-btn.cs-btn-primary';
var BtnCookie = [
  btncookie1, 
  btncookie2
];


(async function () {

//I read the url file
var fs = require('fs');
var urlArray = fs.readFileSync('url-list.js').toString().split("\n").filter(a => a);

//Launch Puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  executablePath: systemPath,
  args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage','--no-sandbox','--window-size=1920,1080'],
  defaultViewport: null
});


//Loop through all the url-list.js URL
var contaUrl = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++){

//Check if empty spaces are present in the url file list
if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){    

//I open the boswser, delete the cache and set the page size
const page = await browser.newPage();
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies');
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');

await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
await page.setViewport({width: device_width, height: device_height});
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');

//Tell me which URL you are working on
console.log(' ');
console.log('\x1b[33m%s','Open URL > '+urlArray[i],'\x1b[0m');
console.log(' ');
await page.goto(urlArray[i],{waitUntil:'networkidle2'}); 
await page.waitFor(20000);

//Find the class / id of the button on the page to accept cookies
var contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie = BtnCookie.length;
for(var n = 0; n <= BtnCookie.length; n++){

if (await page.$(BtnCookie[n]) !== null ) {

console.log(BtnCookie[n]);
const navigationPromise = page.waitForSelector(BtnCookie[n]);
await page.click(BtnCookie[n]); 
await navigationPromise; 

    console.log('\x1b[32m%s', 'Bypass Cookie... OK!','\x1b[0m');
    break;
    }else if (n == contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie) {

        console.log('\x1b[31m%s', 'Cookie not found!','\x1b[0m');
    }else {

        //console.log('I'm looking for the cookie...');
    }

} //end - Find the class / id of the button on the page to accept cookies


//Scroll the entire page to load the content
await autoScroll(page);

async function autoScroll(page){
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var totalHeight = 0;
          var distance  = 100;

          var timer = setInterval(() => {
              var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
              window.scrollBy(0, distance);
              totalHeight += distance;

              if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  resolve();
              }
          }, 300);
      });
  });
}

//Go back to the top of the page
await page.evaluate(_ => {window.scrollTo(0, 0);});

await page.waitFor(10000);

//I clean up the URL before saving the file
var str = urlArray[i];
str = str.replace(/[^\w]+/ig,'-');
var convertiUrl = str;

//SAVE screenshot
await page.screenshot({path: './screenshot/'+convertiUrl+i+'.jpg', fullPage: true});
await page.waitFor(5000);

await page.close();

}//end if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){  

}//end loop

browser.close();

console.log(' ');
console.log('\x1b[32m%s', contaUrl+' all screenshot saved :)','\x1b[0m');
console.log(' ');

})(); //end script
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3688#issuecomment-453218745) should help.

Comment: @tomerpacific, i tried but it doesn't work for me .. :( where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these line to resize viewport after the `page.goto` method:

```
...

await page.goto(urlArray[i],{timeout: 0, waitUntil:'networkidle2'});
await page.waitFor(20000);
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
});

//Find the class / id of the button on the page to accept cookies
var contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie = BtnCookie.length;
...
```

Comment: Thank you. tried but it doesn't work. I would like to save the screenshot with a fixed width at 1920px and with the total height of the page.

Comment: using pagegoto, and if for some strange reason the web page fails or is not fully loaded, setting the timeout to 0, does the browser always wait and not continue with the script?  I was noticing that with slow connections sometimes there is no standard timeout to use.